# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError while running deep learning model on Google Colaboratory

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run on cloud this deep learning model:
https://github.com/razvanmarinescu/brgm#image-reconstruction-with-pre-trained-stylegan2-generators
What I do is simply utilizing their Colab Notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G7_CGPHZVGFWIkHOAke4HFg06-tNHIZ4?usp=sharing#scrollTo=qMgE6QFiHuSL
When I try to exectute:

```
!python recon.py recon-real-images --input=/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/EDGEconnect/val_imgs --masks=/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/EDGEconnect/val_masks --tag=brains --network=dropbox:brains.pkl --recontype=inpaint --num-steps=1000 --num-snapshots=1
```

I receive this error:

```
args: Namespace(command='recon-real-images', input='/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/EDGEconnect/val_imgs', masks='/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/EDGEconnect/val_masks', network_pkl='dropbox:brains.pkl', num_snapshots=1, num_steps=1000, recontype='inpaint', superres_factor=4, tag='brains')
Local submit - run_dir: results/00004-brains-inpaint
dnnlib: Running recon.recon_real_images() on localhost...
Processing image 1/4
Loading networks from "dropbox:brains.pkl"...
Setting up TensorFlow plugin "fused_bias_act.cu": Preprocessing... Loading... Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recon.py", line 270, in <module>
    main()
  File "recon.py", line 263, in main
    dnnlib.submit_run(sc, func_name_map[subcmd], **kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/submission/submit.py", line 343, in submit_run
    return farm.submit(submit_config, host_run_dir)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/submission/internal/local.py", line 22, in submit
    return run_wrapper(submit_config)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/submission/submit.py", line 280, in run_wrapper
    run_func_obj(**submit_config.run_func_kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/recon.py", line 189, in recon_real_images
    recon_real_one_img(network_pkl, img_list[image_idx], masks, num_snapshots, recontype, superres_factor, num_steps)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/recon.py", line 132, in recon_real_one_img
    _G, _D, Gs = pretrained_networks.load_networks(network_pkl)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/pretrained_networks.py", line 83, in load_networks
    G, D, Gs = pickle.load(stream, encoding='latin1')
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/network.py", line 297, in __setstate__
    self._init_graph()
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/network.py", line 154, in _init_graph
    out_expr = self._build_func(*self.input_templates, **build_kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 395, in G_synthesis_stylegan2
  File "<string>", line 359, in layer
  File "<string>", line 106, in modulated_conv2d_layer
  File "<string>", line 75, in apply_bias_act
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/ops/fused_bias_act.py", line 68, in fused_bias_act
    return impl_dict[impl](x=x, b=b, axis=axis, act=act, alpha=alpha, gain=gain)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/ops/fused_bias_act.py", line 122, in _fused_bias_act_cuda
    cuda_kernel = _get_plugin().fused_bias_act
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/ops/fused_bias_act.py", line 16, in _get_plugin
    return custom_ops.get_plugin(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0] + '.cu')
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/custom_ops.py", line 156, in get_plugin
    plugin = tf.load_op_library(bin_file)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.7/tensorflow_core/python/framework/load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/_cudacache/fused_bias_act_237d55aca3e3c3ec0547da06888d8e66.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder4AttrENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I found that the very last part of an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /content/drive/MyDrive/boeing/brgm/brgm/dnnlib/tflib/_cudacache/fused_bias_act_237d55aca3e3c3ec0547da06888d8e66.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder4AttrENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Can be solved by changing a flag in Cuda Makefile: https://github.com/mgharbi/hdrnet_legacy/issues/2 or by installing tf 1.14(colab runs on 1.15.2 and this change made no positive effect).

My question is, how can I get rid  of this error, is there an option to change smth inside Google Colab's Cuda Makefile?

Comment: Hi! Did you try with 1.14 GPU yet?                              
https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada/issues/79#issuecomment-768097355

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't help unfortunately